# how do i combine results in mysql from 3 different tables with unique id

Tags: mysql, sql, string, group-by

Here is the situation i have 3 tables lets say
`cust_data`, `deposit_data`, `transaction_info`:

- in cust_data I have Firstname, Lastname, Email ,Phone, customer_id
- in deposit_data I have deposit_id, deposit_data,date,amount
- in transaction_info I have customer_id,deposit_id, email, transaction_date,processor

Now I need to list all info of the customer with all the deposits he made for example:

```
cust_info : (Firstname, Lastname, Email ,Phone, customer_id) 
1) John , smith , johnsmith@bla.com, 11111111, 111-111-111 
2) Sara , sugar , sarasugar@lala.com, 22222222, 222-222-222

Deposit_data: (deposit_id, deposit_data,date,amount) 
1) 187823 , " some processing info card number...." , 10/10/2019 , 100 
2) 908202 , " some processing info card number...." , 11/11/2019 , 90 
3) 323243 , " some processing info card number...." , 12/12/2019 , 100


transaction_info: (customer_id,deposit_id, email, transaction_date,processor) 
1) 111-111-111 , 908202 , johnsmith@bla.com , 11/11/2019 , googlepay 
2) 111-111-111 , 187823 , johnsmith@bla.com , 10/10/2019 , visa 
3) 222-222-222 , 323243 , sarasugar@lala.com, 12/12/2019 , visa
```

Now I want to make 1 query that will show me all the deposits the customer made so the result will look like:

```
customer_id,Firstname, Lastname, Email ,Phone, amount(bydate) :
111-111-111 John , smith , johnsmith@bla.com ,11111111 , (10/10/2019 : 100 | 10/10/2019 : 90)
```

Better if I can make everything in the same statement, I just dont know how to combine all 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY GROUP_CONCAT INNER JOIN, gives you the answer
Dates should always be saved in MySQL format, or else, when you have to use functions with it , you have to convert them always

> ```
> CREATE TABLE cust_info (
>   `Firstname` VARCHAR(4),
>   `Lastname` VARCHAR(5),
>   `Email` VARCHAR(18),
>   `Phone` INTEGER,
>   `customer_id` VARCHAR(11)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO cust_info
>   (`Firstname`, `Lastname`, `Email`, `Phone`, `customer_id`)
> VALUES
>   ('John', 'smith', 'johnsmith@bla.com', '11111111', '111-111-111'),
>   ('Sara', 'sugar', 'sarasugar@lala.com', '22222222', '222-222-222');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Deposit_data (
>   `deposit_id` INTEGER,
>   `deposit_data` VARCHAR(39),
>   `date` VARCHAR(10),
>   `amount` INTEGER
> );
> ```

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO Deposit_data
>   (`deposit_id`, `deposit_data`, `date`, `amount`)
> VALUES
>   ('187823', ' some processing info card number....', '10/10/2019', '100'),
>   ('908202', ' some processing info card number....', '11/11/2019', '90'),
>   ('323243', ' some processing info card number....', '12/12/2019', '100');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE transaction_info (
>   `customer_id` VARCHAR(11),
>   `deposit_id` INTEGER,
>   `email` VARCHAR(18),
>   `transaction_date` varchar(10),
>   `processor` VARCHAR(9)
> );
> ```

> 

> ```
> INSERT INTO transaction_info
>   (`customer_id`, `deposit_id`, `email`, `transaction_date`, `processor`)
> VALUES
>   ('111-111-111', '908202', 'johnsmith@bla.com', '11/11/2019', 'googlepay'),
>   ('111-111-111', '187823', 'johnsmith@bla.com', '10/10/2019', 'visa'),
>   ('222-222-222', '323243', 'sarasugar@lala.com', '12/12/2019', 'visa');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT 
>     ci.customer_id,
>     ci.Firstname,
>     ci.Lastname,
>     ci.Email,
>     ci.Phone
>     ,
>     group_concat(
>             dd.date, ' : ', dd.amount 
>             order by dd.date
>             separator ' | ') 'amount(bydate)'
> FROM
>     cust_info ci
>         INNER JOIN
>     transaction_info ti ON ti.customer_id = ci.customer_id
>         INNER JOIN
>     Deposit_data dd ON dd.deposit_id = ti.deposit_id
> GROUP BY ci.customer_id , ci.Firstname , ci.Lastname , ci.Email , ci.Phone
> ```
>
> ```
> customer_id | Firstname | Lastname | Email              |    Phone | amount(bydate)                    
> :---------- | :-------- | :------- | :----------------- | -------: | :---------------------------------
> 111-111-111 | John      | smith    | johnsmith@bla.com  | 11111111 | 10/10/2019 : 100 | 11/11/2019 : 90
> 222-222-222 | Sara      | sugar    | sarasugar@lala.com | 22222222 | 12/12/2019 : 100
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5179973e25c831ca5ffbbe14e0529e0)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use string aggregation. A correlated subquery might be more efficient than joins and outer aggregation:

```
select 
    c.*,
    (
        select group_concat(
            d.date, ' : ', d.amount 
            order by d.date
            separator ' | '
        from transaction_info t
        inner join deposit_data d on d.deposit_id = t.deposit_id
        where t.customer_id = c.customer_id
    
    )
from cust_info c
```

You can add a `where` clause to the outer query to filter on a given customer if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use next query as solution:

```
 select 
    ci.customer_id,
    Firstname,
    Lastname,
    ci.Email,
    Phone,
    group_concat(CONCAT(dd.date, ' : ', dd.amount)SEPARATOR ' | ') deposit
  from cust_info ci
  left join transaction_info ti on ci.customer_id = ti.customer_id
  join Deposit_data dd on dd.deposit_id = ti.deposit_id
  group by ci.customer_id, Firstname, Lastname, ci.Email, Phone
  ;
```

Here you can look [working example](https://phpize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=577c763c387b9221018710c4750c0c46)

Answer (score -1):

You need an inner join select statment.

```
SELECT * FROM cust_info c INNER JOIN transaction_info t ON c.cusomter_id = t.customer_id INNER JOIN deposit_data d ON d.deposit_id = t.deposit_id
```

This should be work fine